# ReSharper overwrites VS shortcut no matter what

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm experimenting with ReSharper and really want to love it but ran into a major issue.

I like to use " CTRL + ," to open files without mousing to the solution explorer. ReSharper has an alternative use for this button combo. It politely asks my preference and I select the visual studio option.

[image: Popup Options]

It works once, then switches to the ReSharper option for all subsequent uses.

I can go into ReSharper settings to reverse this but then it asks the polite question again, accepts my answer and ignores my preference again!

This is bad on its own but I'm guessing I'll run into other similar issues as I experiment further. How can I convince ReSharper that I really do like the "Navigate To" better than the "GoToRecentFiles"?

Comment: Why don't you try using Go To Everything (Ctrl+T)? ReSharper augments and replaces lots of VS functionality, but you have to get adjusted to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

In VS Tools - > Options -> Environment -> Keyboard